# Getting an internal server error upon delete being pressed

Tags: angular, mean

```
ERROR Error Code: 500
Message: Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/api/update/5de40f285e9c793ed4af996c: 500 Internal Server Error
```

[image]

image one is api service

[image]

First block of code is from the api service and 2nd block is editcomponent

```
UpdateStudent(id, data: Student): Observable<any> {
        let API_URL = `${this.endpoint}/update/${id}`;
        return this.http.put(API_URL, data, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
          catchError(this.errorMgmt)
        )
      }
```

Api service code

```
updateStudentForm() {
        console.log(this.studentForm.value)
        var id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to update?')) {
          this.studentApi.UpdateStudent(id, this.studentForm.value).subscribe(res => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/students-list'))
          });
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: If you got an error with status code 500: It means there is an error in your server (Inspect your API).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see your error, you can use `catchError` to trap that, modify your service like the following :

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class StudentApiService {

  UpdateStudent(id, data: Student): Observable<any> {
        let API_URL = `${this.endpoint}/update/${id}`;

        return this.http.put(API_URL, data, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log("Daten:", data)),
        catchError(this.handleError),
      )
   }


  private setHttpHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
  }

  private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
    console.error("observable error: ", error);
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }

}
```

Now you can see your error in the **browser -> console** tab

If you got an error with status code 500: It means there is an error in your server (Inspect your API)